# How to save a command from terminal in a file

Tags: linux, shell, terminal

I want to save all the commands that are fired in the terminal. Using history and appending it to a file using cron job method is not suitable for my case.

If anyone types a ls -lrt in the terminal and as soon as he presses the Enter, I want to store it in a file. Any logical explanation would do, I would write the code myself.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/93566/how-to-log-all-bash-commands-by-all-users-on-a-server

Comment: Requests for recommendations are off-topic for StackOverflow. Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: Investigate the `script` command and/or `sudosh`.